# putting ads in my iphone application

Tags: iphone, iad

i wanna put my own banner ads in my iPhone application instead of using admob or iAd services.
Is this allowed or apple prohibits such behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed as long as the purpose of your app is not primarily advertising.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of developers only run their own ads for their own apps inside their apps, so it certainly seems to be allowed.

If want to run your own ad service, make sure to comply with Apple's various terms regarding such things as privacy and content ratings.